# I have a problem with this error message.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, knn

I'm trying to implement KNN from scratch in python. all functions worked correctly until I got to the main() function

```
import csv
import random
import math
import operator

with open('iris.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in lines:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

This is where I created a function to read the iris.csv file

```
def loadDataset(filename, split, trainingSet=[] , testSet=[]):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
        dataset = list(lines)
        for x in range(len(dataset)-1):
            for y in range(4):
                dataset[x][y] = dataset[x][y]
            if random.random() < split:
                trainingSet.append(dataset[x])
            else:
                testSet.append(dataset[x])
```

This is where I test the function

```
trainingSet=[]
testSet=[]
loadDataset('iris.csv', 0.66, trainingSet, testSet)
print('Train: ' + repr(len(trainingSet))) 
print('Test: ' + repr(len(testSet)))
```

This is the distance function

```
def euclideanDistance(instance1, instance2, length):
    distance = 0
    for x in range(length):
        distance += pow((instance1[x] - instance2[x]), 2)
    return math.sqrt(distance)
```

Testing the distance function

```
data1 = [2, 2, 2, 'a']
data2 = [4, 4, 4, 'b']
distance = euclideanDistance(data1, data2, 3)
print('Distance: ' + repr(distance))
```

Neighbors function

```
def getNeighbors(trainingSet, testInstance, k):
    distances = []
    length = len(testInstance)-1
    for x in range(len(trainingSet)):
        dist = euclideanDistance(testInstance, trainingSet[x], length)
        distances.append((trainingSet[x], dist))
    distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    neighbors = []
    for x in range(k):
    neighbors.append(distances[x][0])
    return neighbors
```

testing the neighbors function

```
trainSet = [[2, 2, 2, 'a'], [4, 4, 4, 'b']]
testInstance = [5, 5, 5]
k = 3
neighbors = getNeighbors(trainSet, testInstance, 1)
print(neighbors)
```

function for getting response

```
def getResponse(neighbors):
    classVotes = {}
    for x in range(len(neighbors)):
        response = neighbors[x][-1]
        if response in classVotes:
            classVotes[response] += 1
        else:
            classVotes[response] = 1
    sortedVotes = sorted(classVotes.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return sortedVotes[0][0]
```

testing out the function

```
neighbors = [[1,1,1,'a'], [2,2,2,'a'], [3,3,3,'b']]
response = getResponse(neighbors)
print(response)
```

accuracy function

```
def getAccuracy(testSet, predictions):
    correct = 0
    for x in range(len(testSet)):
        if testSet[x][-1] is predictions[x]:
            correct += 1
    return (correct/float(len(testSet))) * 100.0
```

testing the accuracy function

```
testSet = [[1,1,1,'a'], [2,2,2,'a'], [3,3,3,'b']]
predictions = ['a', 'a', 'a']
accuracy = getAccuracy(testSet, predictions)
print(accuracy)
```

Here comes the main() where the error lies

```
#main
def main():
    # prepare data
    trainingSet=[]
    testSet=[]
    split = 0.67
    loadDataset('iris.csv', split, trainingSet, testSet)
    print ('Train set: ' + repr(len(trainingSet)))
    print ('Test set: ' + repr(len(testSet)))
    # generate predictions
    predictions=[]
    k = 3
    for x in range(len(testSet)):
        neighbors = getNeighbors(trainingSet, testSet[x], k)
        result = getResponse(neighbors)
        predictions.append(result)
        print('> predicted=' + repr(result) + ', actual=' + repr(testSet[x][-1]))
    accuracy = getAccuracy(testSet, predictions)
    print('Accuracy: ' + repr(accuracy) + '%')

main()
```

but when I get to the main() function, I get this error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-ba4ef0fcfe9f> in <module>()
     18     print('Accuracy: ' + repr(accuracy) + '%')
     19 
---> 20 main()

<ipython-input-68-ba4ef0fcfe9f> in main()
     11     k = 3
     12     for x in range(len(testSet)):
---> 13         neighbors = getNeighbors(trainingSet, testSet[x], k)
     14         result = getResponse(neighbors)
     15         predictions.append(result)

<ipython-input-62-d13cbe2070b3> in getNeighbors(trainingSet, testInstance, k)
      3     length = len(testInstance)-1
      4     for x in range(len(trainingSet)):
----> 5         dist = euclideanDistance(testInstance, trainingSet[x], length)
      6         distances.append((trainingSet[x], dist))
      7     distances.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))

<ipython-input-60-93ee3f7cf267> in euclideanDistance(instance1, instance2, 
length)
      2     distance = 0
      3     for x in range(length):
----> 4         distance += pow(float(instance1[x] - instance2[x]), 2)
      5     return math.sqrt(distance)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: `instance1[x]` and `instance2[x]` are strings. You can't subtract strings from each other.

Comment: Waaay too much code. You can research the error and start tracing it back.

Comment: please read this _carefully_: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

You have posted way too much code, but fortunately the error message and the stack trace are clear: You are trying to "subtract" two things that are strings, not numbers. The `csv` package will return everything as a string, so you need to explicitly convert numeric columns to `int` (or `float`) in the result before you can treat them as numbers.

Comment: Thank you Alexis. I tried converting it to float: dataset[x][y] = float(dataset[x][y]). But I got this error message: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'swidth'. How do I get by this?

Comment: `swidth` is hopefully on the last column: skip it. You should only convert the numeric columns 0, 1, 2 (i.e. `for y in range(3)`).